# Combining CollectionView Layouts

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have 2 layouts, one for some random image size and the other for floating section headers

Since there is no multiple inheritence in obj-c, I find it hard to understand how I can use 2 kinds of layouts without mushing both into one layout (since one of the layouts is cocoapod, I want to keep it updated and not fork it).

Both layouts override `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` and `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange`

Since each layout is basically in charge of different aspects of the collectionview layout and they are not conflicting, how can I use both?

Comment: You can create other layout that will contain the layouts. It likes to pattern Facade http://goo.gl/wGjll2

Comment: is that a viable strategy in obj-c?

Comment: I don't like inheritance, therefore I use composition everywhere I can. And Obj-c does not contain multiple inheritance. I think if you want to use both classes without rewrite their, you should create some joining object.

Comment: It's also possible to subclass the layout in the CocoaPod, call `super` implementations, then configure your own stuff. I agree composition is a good technique, but for a lot of UIKit, subclassing is the idiomatic solution.